# Add tooltip to expand child row button in Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, tooltip

I wanted to add a tooltip in the plus/minus green/red button, see 
[this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/custom-renderer.html). How can I achieve that?

Comment: make it like this `<td class="sorting_1" title="Tooltip text for that element">Airi</td>`

Answer (score 6):

> **SOLUTION**

Use the code below:

```
$('body').tooltip({
   selector: 'td.details-control',
   title: 'Click to expand',
   container: 'body',
   placement: 'right'
});
```

> **DEMO**

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('body').tooltip({
    selector: 'td.details-control',
    title: 'Click to expand',
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'right'
  });  
  
    var data = [{"name":"Tiger Nixon","position":"System Architect","salary":"$320,800","start_date":"2011/04/25","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"5421"},{"name":"Garrett Winters","position":"Accountant","salary":"$170,750","start_date":"2011/07/25","office":"Tokyo","extn":"8422"},{"name":"Ashton Cox","position":"Junior Technical Author","salary":"$86,000","start_date":"2009/01/12","office":"San Francisco","extn":"1562"}];
  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": data,
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex){
           $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]', row).tooltip();
        }
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
            
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]', tr.next('tr')).tooltip();
        }
    } );
 
} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: With your solution you can edit the columns, but its something i can't do in my project , because i have made a angular js directive which renders the datatable. I use the responsive option so the plus/minus button is automatically generated when i hide a row or if there are hidden rows. is there a way i can set an id/class to this button in order to add the tooltip?

Comment: @DarkAngeL, the trick is that I'm using `selector` option which will automatically add this tooltip to all datatables. Just use the code in the answer and you don't need any extra code.